# UL inside UL JQuery Problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I've got the following UL's setup:

```
<ul class="parent">
   <li>
      <ul class="child">
         <li>
            test
         </li>
     </ul> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to .append() to only "parent" with the following code:

```
$('ul.parent li:first-child').before(msg);
$('ul.parent:empty').append(msg);
```

It works, however, it's adding msg to both the "parent" UL and the "child" UL.  I know it's because I'm using first-child (or highly suspect anyways).  How can I access JUST the "parent" UL?  I've looked around and just can't seem to find the answer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the child combinator `>` for matching only the immediate `li`:

```
$('ul.parent > li:first-child').before(msg);
```

Comment: Yay for the direct child selector!

Comment: @Lamoni: Don't forget to mark the answer accepted with the checkmark (you can do this after 15 minutes).